# What's the difference between SFA99 and RIBA Agreements 2010 in the UK?

Tags: contractors, architecture

I am starting the process of having an extension on my house, and getting close to signing an agreement with an architect to have drawings done.

The architect would like to use SFA99 as the contract between us, however a cursory Google suggests that RIBA 2010 supersedes it. I can't compare the difference between the two as the documents are locked behind paywalls.

Should I care? What's the difference?

Comment: I can't comment about architect contracts, as my experience is with the JCT construction contracts. However, it certainly isn't uncommon for superceded contracts to be in use after their replacement is published. People tend to use what they are comfortable with.Ask the architect for a copy of the contract and have a read of it. If you're happy with it, sign away.

Comment: Questions on contracts and contractors are explicitly off topic

Comment: I've flagged as off-topic